# Get only data from last year in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I created a hiking app where I can document where I has been.
Now with the new year I have a little problem.
I have made a menubar and a button to a new site to show the hikings from 2021, my problem is I don't get it done, my hiking from today is shown too.

I think I have a problem with my database because my "creationTime" is defined as a TEXT.
But when I create the hiking entry I formatted the creationTime to "dd.MM.yyyy"

```
 return sql.openDatabase(path.join(dbPath, 'wanderwege.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE user_places(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, image TEXT,image2 TEXT, image3 TEXT, createTime TEXT, place TEXT, description TEXT, duration TEXT, kilometers Text, verticalMeters Text, loc_lat REAL, loc_lng REAL, address TEXT)');
    }, version: 1);
```

So I thought I need to change my function "getData" , I tried it, with a WHERE creationTime < 01.01.2021 but then no entries are showed.

```
static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData(String table) async {
    final db = await DBHelper.database();
    return db.query(table);
    //var result =
    //await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM "user_places" WHERE createTime < "01.01.2021"');
    //return result.toList();
  }
```

My second idea is, to create a ne database for 2021, but I'm sure there must be a way to filter my entries.

I checked my db and my test dates are 06.10.2021 , 01.01.2022 and 04.01.2022

If I do

```
await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM "user_places" WHERE createTime = "06.10.2021"');
```

I get the only entry with 06.10.2021. but if I change it to

```
await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM "user_places" WHERE createTime BETWEEN "01.01.2021" AND "31.12.2021"');
```

I get every three entries also the two from 2022, I dont get it.

Comment: You should store the dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD which is comparable.

Comment: but now I can't change my data from one year ?
Can i format it for the query ?

Comment: You should change your data. All SQLite's datetime functions don't work with any other format.